# OpenCV reading too few pixels per row from camera

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, camera

I am trying to fetch a video stream from a camera connected to the serial camera interface on my Raspberry pi 4. To read the video stream I'm using OpenCV and I have set the resolution to the maximum supported as listed by

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

The output from this can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYQJm.jpg
When scaling and showing the image using `imshow` it produces the strange output as seen here:
[image] 
I have tried setting different resolutions and for lower resolutions the "bug" disappears, but the image doesn't entirely fit in the window, meaning some pixels are left out. I have also tried changing pixel format, to both H264 and MJPEG but this only gives me a `VIDIOC_STREAMON: Operation not permitted`.
My code:

```
int testCamera(){
    VideoCapture stream = VideoCapture(0);
    if (!stream.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "failed to start video stream" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    stream.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 4056);
    stream.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 3040);
    int frameWidth = stream.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frameHeight = stream.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    std::cout<<frameWidth<<"x"<<frameHeight<<std::endl; //Prints 4056x3040
 
    Mat frame;
    Mat resized;
    while(1){
        stream >> frame;
 
        resize(frame, resized, Size(1280, 720));
        imshow("frame", resized);
        if (waitKey(10) == 27) break;
    }
}
```

Is this a hardware fault rather than a mismatch in OpenCV? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try widths that are single increments smaller or larger than what you *think* you need to put there. are those accepted, i.e. result in `isOpened` and non-empty frames?

Comment: Paste the code in the question, I cannot access it through the link.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Success! I tried lowering the width and the image is no longer "clipping". It is however, blueish but that is another problem. Do you have any idea why the stated resolution is different?

Comment: @pptaszni Thank you, I included the code in the question.

Comment: hint: you can save the `resize` call. `namedWindow()` with `WINDOW_NORMAL`, makes it resizable using the mouse. likely does nearest neighbor interpolation. you can add `| WINDOW_OPENGL` to get OpenGL, which does linear interpolation.

Comment: no I have no idea why it behaves like this. all I can think of is that there's some implicit padding, that the claimed "supported" resolutions are incorrect by that amount. opencv merely uses V4L apis, so you should be able to reproduce the issue using `guvcview`, VLC, or whatever else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi camera has a [basic block size of 32x16](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html#picamera.PiResolution.pad) which means all image sizes are padded up till the width is a multiple of 32 pixels and the height is a multiple of 16 pixels.

In your case, 4056x3040 would become 4064x3040.

That actually makes your camera 12MP, so you must have the newer Raspberry Pi High Quality Camera.

Whilst I am certain it applies to the V1 and V2 camera, I am not 100% certain that the 32x16 rule applies to High Quality Camera, but it seems likely. I am happy to be corrected if anyone has better information/sources.

---

Just for reference, the v2 Raspberry Pi Camera reports this:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :     yuv420p :     Planar YUV 4:2:0 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :     yuyv422 :           YUYV 4:2:2 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :       rgb24 :     24-bit RGB 8-8-8 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Compressed:       mjpeg :            JFIF JPEG : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Compressed:        h264 :                H.264 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Compressed:       mjpeg :          Motion-JPEG : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       : Unsupported :           YVYU 4:2:2 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       : Unsupported :           VYUY 4:2:2 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :     uyvy422 :           UYVY 4:2:2 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :        nv12 :         Y/CbCr 4:2:0 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :       bgr24 :     24-bit BGR 8-8-8 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       :     yuv420p :     Planar YVU 4:2:0 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       : Unsupported :         Y/CrCb 4:2:0 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x10051c0] Raw       : Unsupported :  32-bit XBGR 8-8-8-8 : {32-3280, 2}x{32-2464, 2}
```

Comment: That is indeed the output I get. It is an Arducam, however. I must say I'm not sure whether that is an official brand or not. One question: how come 1080 is a supported height when it's not a multiple of 16?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. If you, or anyone else, has a better answer, please feel free to add it. I'm always happy to learn. Maybe you could clarify if 4064x3040 works, and add your camera model so our collective knowledge is improved.

Comment: Certainly. Currently, 4032x3040 works. It is however extremely slow, which is to be expected seeing as the Raspberry Pi 4 GPU isn't made for these sizes. The camera I'm using is the Arducam IMX477 12 MP camera for Raspberry Pi.