# OpenCV Image Capture Issue

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, camera, raspbian-buster

I seem to be having an issue capturing images with OpenCv on my Pi 4 Buster. When I try to capture an image using OpenCV, it comes out like this:
[Image Captured via OpenCV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niX9P.jpg)

Anyone know what may be causing the image to appear this way?

I have tested the camera using the raspistill command, the image appears as it should when I do this. I have been using OpenCV version 2.4.9.1 on Pi 3 Stretch for several years without issue. I am currently trying to upgrade to Pi 4 Buster. When I cloned OpenCV from Github onto the Pi 4 Buster, it gave me version 2.4.13.7. I don't want to switch to a newer version of OpenCV because I'm sure it will break everything else that works.

Comment: Skew lines across an image normally mean you have the frame width wrong, so have a read here about padding https://stackoverflow.com/a/68392453/2836621

Comment: `picamera` or `picamera 2`? Can you post command so I can test with Bullseye and Buster?